# WINAPI USB DEVICE LIST C LIBUSB not any good

Tags: winapi, list, usb, device

I hope someone can help me with this issue. I made an application to read some data from a smartphone and display in an application. It worked fine at my house, so I took it to my friend's house to show him and it didn't work. So after the panic, I realized that the address had changed slightly due to being connected to a new PC not a problem there must be a simple solution on winapi.

```
\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0040#6&ff454f2&0&3#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}\
```

I have only found code for C++ and my app is in C so it's no use. I also found libusb on google, however this doesn't return the full paths like in my example above.

Is there a simple fix like search by GUID? Hope you can help.

BR

This was the LIBUSB I used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <libusb.h>

static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)
{
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0;

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)\n",
            desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
            libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0)
        return (int) cnt;

    print_devs(devs);
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This just returns for example

1033:0194 (bus 1, device 255)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get a list of all the device identifiers on your computer, but it's not really all that simple, especially if you need to filter it for a particular kind of device.

You start with [`SetupDiGetClassDevs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069.aspx).  After enumerating the matching devices, use `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId` to get the device path, like the one shown in your question.